# Blue underline on highlighted letters in Indesign. What does it mean?

Tags: adobe-indesign

So in Indesign CC they've added a "feature" I havent seen before, when I highlight certain single letters in a text box I get a blue highlight (shown below) and I get a popup box with a bunch of different glyphs to replace the letter with. Unfortunately I cant show the popup box since screenshots wont capture it.

Can anyone explain what this feature does and how to turn it off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this link from Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/opentype-fonts.html), just scroll down a little bit. It's a new feature that works with some opentype fonts and lets you know if/when a letter has a different glyph you can use. You can turn it off on preferences -> advanced type.